# Redraw selected area of pixels around the current pixel in processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm new to processing.  I'm trying to change the color(or another parameter like hue, saturation..) of the pixels around every pixel.

I get nothing changed instead of desired result. Please, help anybody (+

```java
PImage imgg;
void setup() {
    size(250,166);  
    imgg = loadImage("input.jpg");
    loadPixels();
    image(imgg,0,0);
}

void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < imgg.width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgg.height; j++) {
           //get the brightness value of the current pixel
           int Bright_coeff = int(brightness(pixels[j*imgg.width+i]));
           //calculate the area around the current pixel
           int Bright_dist = Bright_coeff/10  ;
           //area around that pixel will update its color
           for (int x = 0; x < imgg.width; x++ ){
              for (int y = 0; y < imgg.height; y++){
                  //check if the distance between iterating pixels and current pixel from above cycle is less than Bright_dist
                  if ( dist(x, y, i, j)<Bright_dist ){
                      color qwerty = color(random(1,255),random(1,255),random(1,255)) ;
                      pixels[y*imgg.width+x] = qwerty;
                      updatePixels();
                  }else {
                      updatePixels();
                  }
               }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`loadPixels()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadPixels_.html) loads the pixel data of the current display window.
`loadPixels` has to be done, after the image is drawn to the window by [`image()`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html):

```java
PImage imgg;
void setup() {
    size(128,128);  
    imgg = loadImage("input.jpg");

    image(imgg,0,0);
    loadPixels();
}
```

The display is just updated once, after [`draw()`](https://processing.org/reference/draw_.html) has been executed. [`updatePixels()`](https://processing.org/reference/updatePixels_.html) set the pixel data for the display window. It is sufficient to do that once at the end of `draw()`:

```java
void draw() {

    // [...]

    updatePixels();
}
```